# Naming conflict with multiple namespaces?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm used to Java/C#'s way of handling packages. Even though I do most of my work in C++, I've stayed away from namespaces for a while.

I understand that I can have multiple namespaces as such:

```
namespace A
{
    class Foo;
}

namespace B
{
    namespace C
    {
        class Bar;
    }
}
```

This out well. What I'm trying to wrap my head around is the following scenario:

```
namespace A
{
    class Foo;
}

namespace B
{
    namespace A
    {
        class Bar : public A:Foo //here A shows up as namespace B::A
        {
        };
    }
}
```

In Java, this is what I would do if I would write a wrapper. Say I was trying to port the Artemis framework into my engine. If I needed to write a full wrapper, it would be named something along the lines of `MyEngine.Artemis` package name.

In C++, is this possible? More importantly, is this the appropriate way to approach this kind of task?

Comment: You can use the scoping operator `::` to indicate global scope as well, like e.g. `::A::Foo`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg post that as an answer. I spent a couple of hours trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using an unqualified name in a context such as yours, name lookup will start to inspect the innermost enclosing scopes before outer ones. In particular, any names declared in namespace `B` are considered before any names declared in the global namespace.  
Thus the namespace `B::A` is found first, before `::A` - and clearly there is no member `Foo` in `B::A`. Note that there are two distinct namespaces which can be addressed with `A` in your code, but only one can be found without further qualification.

Hence write

```
namespace B
{
    namespace A
    {
        class Bar : public ::A::Foo
        {
        };
    }
}
```